# How does setInterval() work? Can I use it to change image every hour?

Tags: javascript

I'm working with a project, where the text on a image must be changed every hour.

I use javascript `setinterval()`, and don't know how it works.

If a user of the website reloads the page, will the interval restart after that?

And if it is, how can I prevent it from restarting?

Comment: Yes, the setInterval will be reset. It is best to use server-side scripting for the change of the text.

Comment: I think you need some persitency to save how much time elapsed from the last change and then interogate that value on document.load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the interval will restart when the user reloads. You could use a `Date` object to determine which text to show instead, for example:

```
var texts = [
   'Hello!',
   'You rock!',
   'Have a nice day.',
   'Welcome :)'
];

var text = texts[Math.floor((new Date).getTime()/3600000)%texts.length];

// text will update every hour (when the page is refreshed)
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZbjU/) (Modified to update every 10 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

When the user loads the webpage, the setinterval will start, but when they refresh or navigate to a different page, then the setinterval will not continue counting.

The best way to do this, is to use date in javascript.

So you can do something like.

9am - show this image
10am - show this image
etc...

Answer (score 0):

Identify browser refresh event and store the interval in cache or local storage. Once browser
refresh completes resume interval value